# d3.js selection based on id

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have an HTML table and a button.

This is part of my html table:

```
<tbody>

<tr id="13">

    <td>Dave&#39;s Double Cheeseburger</td>
    <td>800.0</td>
    <td>50.0</td>
    <td>42.0</td>
    <td>48.0</td>
    <td>wendys</td>

    <td>
        <div id="option">
            <button id="13" type="button" name="button">
                click here for graph
            </button>
        </div>
    </td>
```

And my d3.js code is

```
$("button").click(function () {
    var buttonid = this.id
    console.log(buttonid)
    // above uses jQuery to display the id of button clicked

    var chartdata = d3.select("[id='" + buttonid + "']").selectAll("td")
})
```

The JS code isn't causing me any problem but I want to target

```
<tr id = button id>
```

But when I do `d3.select("[tr id='" + buttonid + "']")` it says it's not a valid selector.

Any help with d3.js selection?

Comment: does `d3.select("#" + buttonid)` work?

Comment: You are not allowed to have duplicate IDs in your document. Have a look at the HTML5 [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/dom.html#the-id-attribute) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

You can read up on selections in d3 at [d3-selection](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection). In your case, you probably just need the following basic understanding.

```
  d3.select('tag'); // d3 select elements by tag such as "div"
  d3.select('.class'); // d3 select elements by class such as ".myDivs" 
  d3.select('#id'); // d3 select elements by id such as "#myDiv"
```

That said, your code needs some additional work. Your button id needs to start with a letter (HTML id attributes can't begin with a number) and you can't chain `select` and `selectAll` that way. It seems like you are wanting to select the td element that wraps the button that gets clicked. If so, it needs to be something like the following:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    // get td grandparent of clicked button
    var tdElem = this.parentNode.parentNode;

    // d3 select the td element
    var chartdata = d3.select(tdElem);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work provided your d3 nodes have ids attached to them.

```
d3.select("g[id='" + localid + "']");
```